# can i extract all sent email information from marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions, data, history-tracking

So, I am trying to extract SENT email information from marketing cloud.

I have researched everywhere but can't find a way.

I know I can use Data Views and with the help of sql query I can get the information but data views only offers 6month worth data. I want ALL data from start date of marketing cloud till date of all emails sent from our account.

I want following information:

All emails - Date sent / Name of Email / Subject Line / View in browser url of that email so email is view-able

Can anyone guide me in a right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use [Tracking Extracts](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/).  It will need to be done in chunks of 30-90 day increments though. (30 days in Automation studio for custom range, 90 days in Email Studio - if you still have it listed inside of interactions)

As with all extracts, these will be extracted to the safehouse, and you will need to do a file transfer to get it to your FTP.

These files will be fairly large - so be prepared for some slow upload/download speeds.  Tracking Extracts include pretty much all the information that SFMC collects and is accessible by the end user.

### See [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/) for a link to all the info you can get from tracking extracts

See the sub-categories on the left nav to get more details.

### For the VAWP link, you might want to check out '[SendJobs](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/sendjobs/)' and the 'PreviewURL' field.

My recommendation is to create an automation and just keep editing the timeframe and name of the file and then rerun the automation.

Comment: So, I looked in the tracking extracts and it looks like tracking exacts is basically data stored in Data View which I have already mentioned in my original post that it won't help in my case because it only hold data for last 6 months. In addition to that, I am also looking for "View in browser" URL for each mailing so it is viewable. Any other solution?

Comment: Tracking extracts go back as far as you want - you just need to keep putting in custom dates. I believe the VAWP url is in there, but many of the older sends this url may not be active anymore

Comment: Hi @Gortonington - I was able to extract the data including URL but to view that URL, it asks for marketing cloud login. Any way I can extract the URL that does not require login to view it?

Comment: You could look at doing an API call to get the HTML - SOAP for classic (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_an_email_message_and_recreating_that_message_in_an_html_page.htm) and REST for content builder (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getObjectById). If you need a sample of each individual email, you would likely want to add in the VAWP link into a send log or similar for easy reference later.

Comment: I have not worked with API before so I would appreciate if you could please help me in understanding this approach? how to do it? On a side note, I see the reason view email url is asking for login is because all urls extracted from tracking extract are using this domain "http://members.s7.exacttarget.com/integration/EmailPreview.aspx?mid=" while in general the view in browser email url are like this "http://view.mcd.companyname.com".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70041/discussion-between-kuml-and-gortonington).

Comment: Hi @Gortonington - do you know why "PreviewURL" in sendjob tracking extract report requires a login to view the email? Is there any way to extract preview url of all past sent emails that does not require a login to view?

Comment: That is the only way to get VAWP URL for a job that I know of as a front end user, other than if you stored it in a sendlog or similar tracking DE.  You might want to put in a support case to see if SFMC has another way to get this information in their records.

Comment: But is there a reason why previewURL  / VAWP URL will require a login? When I see preview URL of any of our mailing, it does not require login but only when i extract VAWP URL by tracking extract the data gives me preview url that needs user to login. I have a case open but so far tech support has not been helpful.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington just checking if you got a chance to read my last comment?

Comment: I do not have access to SFMC back-end. I do not know why they set it up that way.

Comment: ok - no problem. I appreciate you help me out and answering all my questions.  (marked answer + 1 )

Answer (score 0):

Check out this absolutely awesome article on how to do this
[Export tracking data from Salesforce Marketing Cloud](https://blog.openbridge.com/export-tracking-data-from-salesforce-marketing-cloud-8a0a4c1f37dc)

In the article you will find lots of screenshots and an in depth explanation on how to do this.

Comment: Please see [answer]. Link only answers are generally not accepted here as they are too reliant on the link working. It is better to summarize the link information here as well as providing the link.